# What do you understand by this RegEx?

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I´m working with VBA and trying to split a string into three columns, almost all strings are like `Company Name 3567782 Agent Name.pdf`

With this pattern I want to match all the text before a space and digits (1st group), the digits (2nd group) and all the text after the space and before the .pdf (3rd group).

```
strPattern = "^(.+)\n(\d{4,10})\n(.+).pdf"
```

I recall spaces in python are `\s` but saw in VBA are `\n`.

Can you help me find the right pattern for what I´m looking for?

Comment: I'll take a look and see what I can come up with but you should put your current regex into https://regex101.com. I find the site to be really, really helpful in not only explaining what different tokens mean but helping to build and test regexes. Once you put in your regex, look at the top right in the EXPLANATION section. It break each character down into what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I put in my comment, I use the https://regex101.com site. There are others but I find this one the most helpful to me.

When I put in your regex

```
^(.+)\n(\d{4,10})\n(.+).pdf
```

and test string

```
Company Name 3567782 Agent Name.pdf
```

the first thing I notice is that the regex does not match the test string (see right side under MATCH INFORMATION).

Here are a couple things that I saw:

1. \n is newline, not space. In regex, space is " ".
2. Your last "." in ".pdf" is not registering as a literal period, it's a token that matches any character. To match a literal period, you need `\.`

If we change those two things it returns three groups that seem to match what you are looking for.

```
^(.+) (\d{4,10}) (.+)\.pdf
```

It looks like for the digits, you are looking for between 4 and 10 digits. If that's correct, it looks like your regex is good. You could put in a handful of example strings into the TEST STRING area and make sure that it works in all cases.

Comment: Thanks, very useful page. I also noticed the final dot thing, ^(.+)\s(\d{4,10})\s(.+)\. do the task. Will also try the space like " " for further tries. Thanks a lot

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the edit... I hadn't noticed that didn't come through.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use either of these:
`(?:(?:([a-zA-Z]+\.?)|(\d+)))`

### capture a-Z greedy with a possible . to allow for the .pdf or capture digits

### this version excludes the space [ ] or \s

or keep the search structured so you can control what goes in and out of each column
`^(\w+\s\w+)|(\d+)|(\w+\s\w+\.\w+$)`
`\b or ^` - word boundary or start of string
`(\w+\s\w+)` - 1st capture \w+ -  any alpha numeric char greedily, followed by 1 x space `(use \s*` or \s+ for more), followed again by alpha numeric greedily
`|(\d+)` - alteration - \d+  - capture just digits
`|(\w+\s\w+.\w+$) - similar to 1st group but allows for the '.' of pdf and bounds to the end of string (\G or $).
you could optionally build the '.' into the 1st group like my top answer, but for neatness and better control I prefer the 2nd.

Comment: How is this answering the question?